# Clojure string to symbol evaluates to wrong result

Tags: clojure

```
user=> ((symbol "or") true false)
false
user=> (or true false)
true
```

Why does the first form evaluate to `false`? I'd imagine the two input forms being equivalent.

Strangely, reversing the order of the arguments works:

```
user=> ((symbol "or") false true)
true
user => (or false true)
true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you evaluate the list `(or true false)`, Clojure first evaluates the first item. In this case, the first item is a symbol that names a macro, so Clojure expands the macro and evaluates the resulting data structure (which would be a `let` form in this case).

On the other hand, when you evaluate the list `((symbol "or") true false)`, Clojure again first evaluates the first item, but in this case, the first item is another list! The first element of *that* list is the symbol `symbol`, which names a function, so Clojure calls that function with the parameter `"or"`, again producing the symbol `or`. In other words, you are basically evaluating `('or true false)`.

Here's the catch: Clojure does not take that thing that it just evaluated and then go and evaluate it again. Rather, since it wasn't a symbol in the first place, Clojure evaluates it and then assumes that it must be a function. Is it a function? Indeed, the answer is yes!

```
user> (ifn? 'do)
;=> true
```

Here's where it gets a little tricky. The implementation of `invoke` on the `Symbol` class is the same as the implementation of `invoke` on the `Keyword` class: it assumes that the first argument is a map and tries to look itself up in that map. If you provide a second argument, it will use that as a default value.

Now, obviously, if you try to treat `true` as a map and look up the symbol `or` in that map, you'll find nothing. So Clojure helpfully returns the default value that you provided: `false`. You could put any value you'd like in that second parameter spot, and as long as your symbol doesn't exist as a key in the first argument, you'll always get back your default value.