# How to quote an argument in clojure

Tags: clojure, arguments, quote

I am new to clojure. I want to use quote in clojure the following way:

First I define a variable:

> (def dog "animal")

And then a function::

> (defn what-is [name]
>
> ('name (str " is an " name)))

If I call the function *what-is* with the variable *dog* as the parameter:
(what-is dog)

The result should be:

USER>> dog is an animal

Here I returned the name of the argument I passed to the function *what-is*, not its value:

What I get instead is:

> is an animal

no mention of the parameter *dog* here.

Again what I am looking for is to repeat "literally" the name of the parameter I pass the function, as in this template:

> (what-is x )=> x is an ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not something that you can do with a function. A function receives only runtime values, not the code that was evaluated to produce those values. If you want to define a piece of code that makes use of the actual source code, rather than the runtime values, you can use a [macro](http://clojure.org/reference/macros):

```
(defmacro what-is [x]
  `(str '~x " is an " ~x))

(what-is dog)
;;=> "dog is an animal"
```

As you can see, this `what-is` macro looks different from your `what-is` function; it makes use of Clojure's syntax-quote reader macro. Rather than being called at runtime with a string as input and returning a string as output, this macro is called at compile time with a piece of code (`x`) at compile time and returns another piece of code, which will then be evaluated. You can use the [`macroexpand-1`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/macroexpand-1) function to see exactly what code the `what-is` macro returns:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(what-is dog))
;;=> (clojure.core/str (quote dog) " is an " dog)
```

If you want, you can then evaluate this expanded piece of code to see that it gives the same result:

```
(clojure.core/str (quote dog) " is an " dog)
;;=> "dog is an animal"
```

Comment: Thank you @Sam Estep. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Any reason why a quoted operator like `('name 5) ; ==> nil` works in Clojure?

Comment: @Sylwester Yes; see my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35541931/5044950). The `Symbol` class provides an implementation of [`invoke`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Symbol.java#L125-L127) that is equivalent to [`get`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do what I think you want to do.  Instead of defining the categories of a variable to be its value, use a Clojure map.  For example using the basic `{}` map syntax:

```
(def what-is-map {"dog"  "animal"
                  "cat"  "animal"
                  "Fiat" "auto"
                  "flu"  "illness"})

(defn what-is [thing]
  (str thing " is an " (what-is-map thing)))
```

The last expression works because maps can be used like functions in many situations.

```
(what-is "dog") ;=> "dog is an animal"
(what-is "flu") ;=> "flu is an illness"
```

You can also provide a default for things that aren't in your map.  Here's one way:

```
(defn what-is [thing]
  (let [what-it-is (what-is-map thing)]
    (if what-it-is
      (str thing " is a " what-it-is)
      (str "I don't know what a " thing " is"))))
```

The `if` works because when a key isn't found in a map, `nil` is returned.  (`nil` is one of the false values.  The other is `false`.)

```
(what-is "fish") ;=> I don't know what a fish is"
```

There are other, perhaps better ways to write these functions, but I wanted to keep things basic.

Comment: @ Mars thanks for your answer. you anticipated one other thing I wanted to implement: having multiple definitions of things. So a map is the best data structure for that.

Comment: @ Mars is there a way to call the function what-is with the parameter passed as a symbol instead of as a string., ie. what-is dog, instead of what-is "dog" ? Thanks again

Comment: Omar, for that you'd need a macro, as in Sam Estep's answer.  However, it's common to use keywords, such as `:dog` as keys for maps, instead of strings or other objects.  I only used strings for keys in my example because I didn't want to throw too many things into the answer all at once.  Normally I would use `{:dog "animal" :cat "animal" ...}` etc., or `{:dog :animal :cat :animal ...}`, or something similar, as my map.

Comment: Also: You can use `name` to convert a keyword to a string, e.g.: `(str thing " is an " (name (what-is-map thing))))`.